# Nginx + node.js + x-SendFile

Tags: node.js, nginx, x-sendfile

I currently have a node.js server behind a nginx reverse proxy.

I would like to know if there is any performance benefits to using x-sendfile, rather than express "static" middleware or "sendFile" express method.

I'm also curious about the reason x-sendfile is so few documented in the comunity of js servers, since it's kind of a common thing to do with a PHP server.